# Drupal 8, file/image field directory tokens

Tags: php, drupal-8

i just installed d8 for the first time (im d7 user). I noticed that when im creating content type, and file/image field, there is directory option with some date tokens:

```
[date:custom:Y]
```

im searching from one hour for more information on drupal site, forums etc. Is there any info about all available tokens by default? Or there are only date? Im looking for token that will use my custom field value or node title. Module "Token" and "File field path" are still in alpha version, but maybe there is possibility to do that from the core modules? Or it is maybe simply to do that inside custom module? Any suggestions will be nice

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a listing of all available tokens (if you have the token module enabled). Just navigate there:

```
/admin/help/token
```

It is planned to have a token browser implemented in core, but it's postponed as stated here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/514990

Comment: there is no such page for drupal 8

Comment: I dont know if it works. But drupal 8 have some tokens in core. I want to find description about it.

Comment: It is planned to be implemented in core, but is not yet. See here: https://www.drupal.org/node/514990 So if you want a nice token browser you can use the token module.

Comment: so i can assume there are no other tokens than "date" in core, or there is no listing only?

Comment: /admin/help/token does indeed exist (at this date), as long as you have the help.module installed.

Answer (score 1):

The source of tokens defined in core modules (and others) are the implementations of [hook_token_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/).  Unfortunately, without installing the [Token contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) you don't get an easy list to review.